# read unix @->/var/run/docker.sock: read: connection reset by peer

Tags: docker

I'm populating `blockchains` database with my backup script `backup_2019-05-21.sql`, but running this command on CLI shows this error.

some_user@my_project:~$ docker exec -i mysql_test mysql -uroot -ptestpass blockchains < /home/some_user/db_backups/backup_2019-05-21.sql
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqldump: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insec' at line 1
read unix @->/var/run/docker.sock: read: connection reset by peer

Note: backup_2019-05-21.sql file size is 5G

Someone know the exact reason ? :)

Comment: You'll probably get the whole error message if you use an ordinary `mysql` client, instead of running it via `docker exec` (you don't normally interact with a database server via a root shell on the console).  That's probably not the root cause of the error, though.

Comment: What does the first line of your backup look like?

Comment: $ head -20 /home/khalid/db_backups/backup_2019-05-22.sql
mysqldump: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 8.0.15, for Linux (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: blockchains1
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version 8.0.15

/*!40101 SET ....
-- Table structure for table `eos_actions`

Comment: @sitetester It looks like there are error and warning messages mixed in with your backup file.

Comment: Yes indeed. There was this `[Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure. ` added on top of the backup file. I removed it using `nano` and it went fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line of your backup:

```
[Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
```

Is not valid sql. It appears to be an error log interspersed with your sql dump. If you can run your backup again, you'll want to do so without capturing these error messages. If that's not possible, you'll need to remove these logs from your sql file before trying to import it.

Comment: You are the man! 
I opened the file using nano and removed the first line, ran backup using `$ docker exec -i mysql_test /usr/bin/mysql -u root --password=testpass blockchains < /home/some_user/db_backups/backup_2019-05-22.sql` and it restored after a while (big file). 

In general, big files should be edited using other better ways.

Comment: It's weird that this `Warning` was auto added at top of the backup file.